# conditional expectation on ranks

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

What is the conditional expectation of a measurable function $f(X_1,\ldots,X_m)$ given the ranks $X_{(1)}<\ldots<X_{(m)}$? The $X_j$ are iid. It must be symmetric to be measurable wrt ranks, and it must have the same expectation as $f$, so I could guess the average over all permutations of $X_1,\ldots,X_m$. Is that so? How to prove that is the actual conditional expectation? If that guess is wrong, is there another simple expression for the conditional expectation?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Once you condition on the order statistics, the only unknown left is the label $1,\dots, m$ . Because the data are iid, all ways of attaching labels $1,\dots, m$ to $X_1,\dots, X_m$ are equally likely, so the conditional expectation is the average over all permutations.